# Any way for a dependency property on a UserControl execute a command on it's view-model on value change?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

Suppose there's a UserControl with a dependency property (a collection of some object) - is there anyway for, when the dependency property is set, to automatically execute a command exposed by the view-model without breaking encapsulation and doing this the "MVVM way"?

And yes I know I can always wire-up the property changed static handler, cast the object to an instance of my user control, grab the data-context, cast that to the view-model and call the command manually

EDIT: maybe an example would help. My UserControl has a "ItemsSource" dependency property ..I want it to be settable to a collection of ObjectA. I have an "Items" dependency property which is only gettable and is a collection of ObjectB.

I want behavior such that if I set ItemSource, my collection of ObjectAs will be transformed one-to-one by the view-model into ObjectBs, and the Items dependency property will automatically reflect this.

To do this I want a write-only ItemsSource and a read-only Items property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it clear:

- You want a write-only DependencyProperty *ItemsSource* on the **Control**
- You want a read-only Dependency-Property *Items* on the control's **ViewModel**
- *Items* should return a transformed version and reflect changes of *ItemsSource*

If that is what you want, would that be a solution:

- Add an ItemsSource-Property to the ViewModel which is the
  same type as in the control
- Two-way-bind it to the control's DP
- In the Set-accessor of the *ItemsSource* property of the
  ViewModel, fill the *Items* collection with transformed versions of
  the *ItemsSource* elements
- Fire OnPropertyChanged for the *Items* property

*ItemsSource* of the Control and ViewModel is readable in this scenario. Write-only DPs are not possible as far as I know:

[SO Thread about write-only DPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315186/how-can-i-create-a-custom-write-only-dependency-property)

However, this approach should work anyway.

Hope this helps, cheers...

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ObservableCollection` you can use it's `CollectionChanged` event.

ViewModel:

```
  private ObservableCollection<object> _Objects
  public ObservableCollection<object> Objects
  {
    get { return _Objects; }
    set { _Objects = value; 
           OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Objects"));
     }
  }

  Objects.CollectionChanged+= new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Objects_CollectionChanged); 

 void Objects_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```